# Why does the value of checkout-price read as null?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to take a string of text from several elements and remove the symbols to turn it into a number, then combine the numbers to get a total value that I then update the total element. I am getting an error that says "cannot read property"length" of null."

This is my code that I'm trying to make, but I'm not sure if I am on the right track.

```
let price_calc = document.querySelectorAll("#checkout-price");
let total = ""
for (i = 0; i <= price_calc.length; i++){
    total += (Number(price_calc[i].textContent.replace(/[^\d|.]/g, "")))
}
let costEl = document.getElementById("total-cost")
costEl.textContent = `$${total}`
```

and HTML:

```
<div class='price' id="checkout-price">$523.61 (GST Inc)</div>
<div class='price' id="checkout-price">$137.23 (GST Inc)</div>
<div class='price' id="checkout-price">$274.20 (GST Inc)</div>
<div class='price_sum'id="total-cost">$00.00</div>
```

I may have the wrong approach for getting the values from the div's. How can I get this calculator working properly?

Comment: Ids are SINGULAR

Comment: this is because your HTML is invalid

Comment: Try this: let price_calc = document.querySelectorAll(".price");

ID's have to be unique so you need to adjust your HTML as well. Kill the ID's if they aren't necessary.

Comment: Please interact with ONE question at a time. We answered your question, so please do not write new similar questions

Answer (score 1):

simply do that

```js
const price_calc = document.querySelectorAll(".price")
  ,   costEl     = document.getElementById("total-cost")
  ;
let total = [...price_calc]
              .reduce((tot,el)=>
                  {
                  tot += Number(el.textContent.replace(/[^\d|.]/g, ""))
                  return tot
                  }
                  ,0)
 
costEl.textContent = `$ ${total}`
```

```html
<div class="price">$ 523.61 (GST Inc)</div>
<div class="price">$ 137.23 (GST Inc)</div>
<div class="price">$ 274.20 (GST Inc)</div>
<div class="price_sum" id="total-cost">$ 00.00</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let price_calc = document.querySelectorAll(".price");
let total = 0

for (i = 0; i < price_calc.length; i++){
    total += parseInt(price_calc[i].innerHTML.replace(/[^\d|.]/g, ""))
}

let costEl = document.getElementById("total-cost")
costEl.textContent = `$${total}`
```

Its important that `total` is an int, so initialize it as 0 instead of an empty string. Also make sure you convert the replaced text to an int with `parseInt()`. If you dont want it to round the floating points use `Number()`
The above code should work.